# LINQ select item from a list where string contains any of the search terms in a list -> refactor

Tags: linq, refactoring

I have list of Items, called Translations. I filter the translations based on a search term from a search box, currently it looks like this:

```
private static IList<Translation> FilterTranslationListOLD(string filter, IEnumerable<Translation> translationList)
{
    filter = filter.ToLower();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
    {

        return translationList
            .Where(t => (t.Tag.Filename.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                            || t.Tag.FilePath.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                            || t.Tag.TagContent.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                            || (t.Tag.SanitizedTagContent != null && t.Tag.SanitizedTagContent.ToLower().Contains(filter))
                            || (t.TagTranslation != null && t.TagTranslation.ToLower().Contains(filter))
                            || (t.SanitizedTranslation != null && t.SanitizedTranslation.ToLower().Contains(filter))))
            .OrderBy(t => t.Tag.FilePath)
            .ThenBy(t => t.Tag.Filename).ThenBy(t => t.Tag.Id).ToList();
    }
    return translationList.OrderByDescending(t => t.DateTranslated).ToList();
}
```

I've now introduced the ability to search with multiple keywords, like so:

```
private static IList<Translation> FilterTranslationList(string filter, IEnumerable<Translation> translationList)
        {
            filter = filter.ToLower();
            var splitFilterTerms = filter.Split(',');

            if (splitFilterTerms.Any(split=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(split)))
            {
                var translationListResults = new List<Translation>();
                foreach (var splitFilterTerm in splitFilterTerms)
                {
                   translationListResults.AddRange(translationList
                   .Where(t => (t.Tag.Filename.ToLower().Contains(splitFilterTerm)
                                   || t.Tag.FilePath.ToLower().Contains(splitFilterTerm)
                                   || t.Tag.TagContent.ToLower().Contains(splitFilterTerm)
                                   || (t.Tag.SanitizedTagContent != null && t.Tag.SanitizedTagContent.ToLower().Contains(splitFilterTerm))
                                   || (t.TagTranslation != null && t.TagTranslation.ToLower().Contains(splitFilterTerm))
                                   || (t.SanitizedTranslation != null && t.SanitizedTranslation.ToLower().Contains(splitFilterTerm))))
                   .OrderBy(t => t.Tag.FilePath)
                   .ThenBy(t => t.Tag.Filename).ThenBy(t => t.Tag.Id).ToList());
                }
                return translationListResults;
            }
            return translationList.OrderByDescending(t => t.DateTranslated).ToList();
        }
```

what I would like to know is, is there a nicer way of writing this? Whilst it works, it would be nice to know how to do it in all linq or reduce/refactor it a little (make it a little neater). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at `SelectMany`, which will help you flatten a sequence of sequences:

```
private static IList<Translation> FilterTranslationListOLD(string filter, IEnumerable<Translation> translationList)
{
    filter = filter.ToLower();
    var splitFilterTerms = filter.Split(',');
    if (splitFilterTerms.Any(split=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(split)))
     {
        return splitFilterTerms.SelectMany(f => translationList
            .Where(t => (t.Tag.Filename.ToLower().Contains(f)
                            || t.Tag.FilePath.ToLower().Contains(f)
                            || t.Tag.TagContent.ToLower().Contains(f)
                            || (t.Tag.SanitizedTagContent != null && t.Tag.SanitizedTagContent.ToLower().Contains(f))
                            || (t.TagTranslation != null && t.TagTranslation.ToLower().Contains(f))
                            || (t.SanitizedTranslation != null && t.SanitizedTranslation.ToLower().Contains(f))))
            .OrderBy(t => t.Tag.FilePath)
            .ThenBy(t => t.Tag.Filename).ThenBy(t => t.Tag.Id)).ToList();
    }
    return translationList.OrderByDescending(t => t.DateTranslated).ToList();
}
```

I haven't actually run this code.  [Here is the MSDN documentation of SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Keeps it all in linq and tidys it up a little. Thanks! I still find linq a little hard to read sometimes (to immediately understand) but i'm not sure if that's a lack of familiarity or because the syntax is very cluttered.

Comment: if you think it is cluttered, you could extract the entire argument to the `Where` clause into a variable of type `Func<Translation, bool>`.  This might make things tidier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above code is that it displays in OR condition and not AND...
So if you have these items:

```
List<Car> Cars = new List<Car>();
Cars.Add(new Car(){Manufacturer="Mercedes Benz", Color="Blue"});
Cars.Add(new Car(){Manufacturer="Mercedes Benz", Color="Green"});
```

it will display both if the filter is "Mercedes Blue"

I used this code to show only the blue car:

```
string Filter = "Mercedes blue";
List<string> SplittedFilter = new List<string>(Filter.ToLowerInvariant().Split(' '));

List<Car> FilteredCars = Cars;

foreach (var item in SplittedFilter) {
    FilteredCars = (from c in FilteredCars
                   where c.Manufacturer.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(item) || c.Color.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(item)
                   select c).ToList();

}
```

Source: http://www.groggyjava.tv/blog/?p=84